# Add Dynamic Contact Id in Marketing cloud Email Level Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, custom-link

How to add contact Id to the website link dynamically in each email in salesforce marketing cloud. I know we could use the below **UTM parameters** to send additional data, but i want to populate one of them dynamically with a record Id.

The reason is, the link that is available on the email is redirected to a global website,so we want to use the contact Id as a identifier to bring back the analytics from Adobe analytics on the global website to salesforce.

Below are the UTM parameters

- utm_source
- utm_medium
- utm_campaign
- utm_term
- utm_content

I'm open for any other suggestions other than using these existing parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you contact Id is the subscriber key why don't you use the personalisation string: %%_subscriberkey%%

You have them [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5).

If you need another value just use the same principle %%myID%% for the sendable DE or even AMPscript to have it  at the end of all links. You can either contact support and have them always insert it or use the AdditionalEmailAttribute.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain more about the contact support part. I didn't quite get that.